# Any specific precautions should be taken when using 2x AA LiSOCL2 batteries in parallel?

Tags: power, batteries, analog, wireless, buck

I am working on the wireless sensor design and one of the sensor is such that it needs to be kept ON through out the operation and it takes supply of 3V and current of about 100uA, which I think is ok to draw from LiSOCL2 (Lithium Thionyle Chloride) battery.

To provide the system with higher battery capacity, if I go with bigger battery, it doesn't fulfill my form factor requirement of the sensor node. So, I have decided to go ahead with 2x AA size LiSOCL2 batteries.

Are there any specific precautions that should be taken while using this configuration and/or using LiSOCL2 batteries?

Comment: Do you mean two or four? Two in series will give 3V.

Comment: @DiBosco I also am confused about these AA size primary (non rechargeable) Lithium cells, LiSOCL2 cells are typically 3.6 V per cell, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_battery So it looks like OP wants to use them in parallel.

Comment: Indeed you can just use 2 of these cells in parallel to have a larger battery capacity. There is only one **but** and that is that the cells need to be similar. So do not combine a fresh one with a used one. As long as both cells are same brand, type and age, I do not see a problem connecting them in parallel.

Comment: Example: a Saft LS14500 AA has a nominal capacity of 2.6 Ah. At 100 uA continously that gives you an expected lifetime of 26000 hours or about 1000 days or almost 3 years. Are you sure that's not enough ?

Comment: Yes I want to use two AA size batteries of 3.6V each in parallel which will give me 3.6V but double the current capacity.

Thanks for suggestions on not combining old and new cell as that will age the new cell also very quickly.

I also want to provide the reverse battery protection. Should I provide protection for each battery individually or provide the protection on the single output voltage after parallel connection of batteries?

Comment: Actually it is not just a sensor that I will run but there is an RF SoC which will periodically wake up and transmit the data. So, after calculations, it comes down that if I use single AA size Saft LS145000 battery, it will last for about 5-6 months. To achieve 1 year of battery life, I need to put two batteries in parallel.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Well you learn summat new every day. I had never come across these before and made the assumption all AAs were 1.2/1.5V.

Comment: @user2365252: If the batteries are user serviceable then all kinds of things will go wrong. For example they will be used to put AA batteries in with opposing polarity, so you need to protect against that. They will put in two different ones with very different charge state and voltage and quality. They will put in 1.5V AA batteries.

Comment: Protect them individually with a Schottky diode. That will protect you from batteries in the wrong way round and from having different voltages.

Comment: @Finbarr, thanks for the advice. I was considering that strongly before I realized that there would be a battery voltage of 3.6V and system operates at 3V. Even if I put best Schottky diode, it will drop 0.3 to 0.4V while supplying the voltage and I will miss out on that amount of battery juice. So, I am thinking of putting PFET on the high side for each battery individually but again, I fear the voltage drop due to PFET similar to diode. What do you suggest?

Comment: What current are you expecting to draw from the batteries when the RF SoC is operating? Also, if you look at the discharge characteristics of these batteries, the output voltage remains pretty much flat until the battery is almost exhausted so you won't miss out on much capacity this way.

Comment: @Finbarr, I am expecting around 30mA of current when RF SoC is operating. I agree on the flat discharge curve.

Comment: Well, at 30mA you'd expect to lose no more than around 200mV with the right Schottky diode. Make sure that you won't end up with too much voltage supplied to the sensor and SoC rather than too little!